# Swift / Xcode: How to Play a Different Sound for Each Day of the Month?

Tags: swift, xcode

Hello and thanks in advance for any ideas!

My simple app has one button that plays a sound when pressed. I'd like the button to play a different sound for each day of the month. Is this possible? If so, what code would accomplish this?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
var musicEffect: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer ()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let musicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "0001", ofType: ".mp3")

    do {
        try musicEffect = AVAudioPlayer (contentsOf: URL (fileURLWithPath: musicFile!))
    }

    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


@IBAction func playMusic(_ sender: Any) {

    musicEffect.play()
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: This is really two problems: 1) How to figure out the day of the month, and 2) How to play a sound depending on some input. Which one are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calendar function `component(_:from:)` would give you the day of the month. From there it's easy:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

let date = Date()
let dayOfMonth = calendar.component(.day, from: date)  //Get the day of the month as an Int
let filename = String(format: "%04d", dayOfMonth)  //Convert to a string "00xx"
let musicFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: ".mp3") //Try to find a sound file
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXwGVXD7qEQ :D

Thank you Duncan for your expertise!

Answer (score 0):

By using `Calendar`'s `component(from:)` method, you can extract the month (or any other date component) from a `Date` object, which will allow you to do what you want.